# How to access arrays of prefabs through the inspector in a given hierarchy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The script below is added to an empty game object `WeaponGroup`, which can be populated using the editor. I have made a new game object `WeaponGroups` which should have a script `SetupWeaponGroupsScript`. How can I transfer the properties below so that each `WeaponGroup` (`SetupWeaponGroupsScript` will have an array of `WeaponGroup` objects) is setup in a way similar to what is done below, so that I make the `SetupWeaponsScript` properties hidden to the inspector and populate them through `SetupWeaponGroupsScript`?

```
public class SetupWeaponsScript {

// Here's our tuple combining a weapon prefab and a direction.
[System.Serializable]
public struct DirectedWeapon {
    public WeaponScript weapon;
    public WeaponScript.Direction direction;
}

// The prefabs array is now this tuple type.
public DirectedWeapon[] weaponPrefabs;
public WeaponScript[] weapons;

void Start ()
{  
    weapons = new WeaponScript[weaponPrefabs.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < weaponPrefabs.Length; i++)
    {
        // Using typed Instantiate to save a GetComponent call.
        weapons[i] = Instantiate<WeaponScript>(weaponPrefabs[i].weapon);
        weapons[i].weaponDir = weaponPrefabs[i].direction;
    }      
}  
}
```

Graphically, I would like to have the following hierarchy in the editor for a new script `SetupWeaponGroupsScript`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should be close :

```
   public class SetupWeaponsScript
    {
        [System.Serializable]
        public struct DirectedWeaponGroup
        {
            public DirectedWeaponScript[] weaponPrefabs;
        }

        // Here's our tuple combining a weapon prefab and a direction.
        [System.Serializable]
        public struct DirectedWeapon
        {
            public WeaponScript weapon;
            public WeaponScript.Direction direction;
        }

        // The prefabs array is now this tuple type.

        public DirectedWeaponGroup[] weaponGroups;

        public DirectedWeapon[] weaponPrefabs;
        public WeaponScript[] weapons;

        void Start()
        {
            weaponGroups = new DirectedWeaponScript[weaponGroups.Length];

            for (int h = 0; h <  weaponGroups.Length; h++)
            {
                weaponPrefabs = weaponGroups[h].weaponPrefabs;
                weaponPrefabs[h] = Instantiate<DirectedWeaponScript>(weaponGroups[h].weaponPrefabs);

                weapons = new WeaponScript[weaponPrefabs.Length];

                for (int i = 0; i < weaponPrefabs.Length; i++)
                {
                    // Using typed Instantiate to save a GetComponent call.
                    weapons[i] = Instantiate<WeaponScript>(weaponPrefabs[i].weapon);
                    weapons[i].weaponDir = weaponPrefabs[i].direction;
                }
            }
        }
```